# Htaccess RewriteRule for different urls to create similar link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i got problem when using those rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)-([0-9]+)$ /all.php?name=$1&m=$2&y=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/year-([0-9]+)$ /year.php?name=$1&y=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

the second rule not working

when i try: `/james/year-2023` it will work based on the first rule.

how can i make `/james/january-2023` work with first rule and `/james/year-2023` work with second rules?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the regex in the first rule is more general and matches URLs you are expecting to be matched by the second rule.

You just need to reverse the two rules so the more specific rule is first:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/year-([0-9]+)$ /year.php?name=$1&y=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)-([0-9]+)$ /all.php?name=$1&m=$2&y=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```